# pyplot.plot() doesn't respect keyword arguments

Tags: matplotlib

In my preamble I have

```
import numpy as np
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cycler import cycler
plt.style.use([
    'seaborn-paper', {'axes.prop_cycle': (
        cycler('color', ['k'])*
        cycler('lw', [2,1])*
        cycler('dashes', [[],[13,2],[8,3,1,3]]))}])
```

When I later use `plt.plot()` using keyword arguments (or their equivalents),
e.g.,

```
a = np.array((0.,5.))
plt.plot(a,a, linewidth=6)
plt.plot(-a,a, '-')
```

I'm expecting a VERY wide 1st line and a continuous 2nd one, but this is what I get

[image: the wrong line types!]

What can I do if I want to

1. have a sensible (for me:) default cycle for the line styles and
2. break the rules here and there?

tia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue as that the aliases for linewidth are not being properly de-aliased (so both `linewidth` and `lw` are being used to set the width and conflicting).  A similar thing is happening with the style string vs linestyle vs dashes.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cycler import cycler
plt.style.use([
    'seaborn-paper', {'axes.prop_cycle': (
        cycler('color', ['k'])*
        cycler('linewidth', [2,1])*
        cycler('dashes', [[],[13,2],[8,3,1,3]]))}])

a = np.array((0.,5.))
plt.plot(a,a, linewidth=6)
plt.plot(-a,a, dashes=[])
```

should work.

The first issue (the lw aliasing) is fixed in 2.x, but even using dashes is the cycle is now broken :(

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7426